# convert bitmap stream to jpeg image in WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm trying to implement upload image from clipboard functionality in my app, following code:

```
var clipboard = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent();

            if (clipboard.contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.bitmap)) {
                clipboard.getBitmapAsync().done(function (stream) {
                    stream.openReadAsync().then(function (bitmapStream) {
                       //TODO
                    });

                });

                return;
            }
```

works and I can upload it, but only as  bitmap. 
What I'd like to achieve is to upload images as jpeg. 
I know I could use canvas element to convert bitmap to jpeg, but is there any other way? 
Maybe something from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few trials, I found solution, code below. Not pretty but works, converts bitmaps from clipboard to png/jpeg, and uploads file to server (almost- ajax request missing here).
Hope it will help someone with similar problem.

```
if (clipboard.contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.bitmap)) {
    clipboard.getBitmapAsync().done(function(bitmap) {
        bitmap.openReadAsync().then(function(bitmapStream) {
            Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.createAsync(bitmapStream).then(function(decoder) {
                decoder.getPixelDataAsync().then(function(pixelDataProvider) {
                    var pixels = pixelDataProvider.detachPixelData();
                    var memoryStream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

                    Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId, memoryStream).then(function(encoder) {
                        encoder.setPixelData(decoder.bitmapPixelFormat, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.ignore,
                                            decoder.orientedPixelWidth, decoder.orientedPixelHeight, decoder.dpiX, decoder.dpiY, pixels);

                        encoder.flushAsync().then(function() {
                            var fileName = 'screenshot_' + moment().format('MMDDYYYY_HHmm') + '.png';
                            var imageblob = MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream('image/png', memoryStream);

                            var formData = new FormData();
                            formData.append('upload', imageblob, imageName);
                        });
                   });
                });
           });
         });
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising. Is this possible in all modern browsers?